# Queue doesn't enter on worker function with Elysia cron

Tags: cron, queue

I'm trying to use queue api with cron, everything seems work but drupal does not enter on the "worker" function.
The problem there is only if I enable Elysia Cron (and I've to enable it..)

```
<?php 

/**
 * Implements hook_cron_queue_info().
 */
function monitor_import_cron_queue_info() {
  $queue['monitor_import_queue'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'monitor_import_queue_worker',
    'time' => 10,
  );
  return $queue;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function monitor_import_cron() {

  $call = new MyWS();
  $params = new getSoggettoView();
  $params->limit = '10'; //$limit;
  $params->offset = '0';
  $results = $call->getSoggettoView($params);
  $items = $results->return;
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('monitor_import_queue'); // grab queue
  $queue->createQueue(); // initialize
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $queue->createItem($item);
  }
}

/**
 * Worker callback
 *
 * @see mymodule_cron_queue_info().
 */
function monitor_import_queue_worker($item) {
  $a = 1;
}
```

Comment: If `$call->getSoggettoView($params);` doesn't return any data to add to the queue, then the worker callback won't get an item to process, i.e won't be called.

Comment: The problem seems elysia_cron

Answer (score 1):

Below code perfectly works for me...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron_queue_info().
*/
function drup_custom_cron_queue_info() {
  $queue['drup_custom_queue'] = array(
      'worker callback' => 'drup_custom_queue_worker',
      'time' => 10,
  );
  return $queue;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function drup_custom_cron() {
  $items = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('drup_custom_queue'); // grab queue
  foreach ($items as $i) {
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item->created = time();
    $item->sequence = $i;
    $queue->createItem($item);
  }
}

/**
 * Worker callback
 *
 * @see mymodule_cron_queue_info().
 */
function drup_custom_queue_worker($item) {
  watchdog('drup_custom', 'Queue worker processed item with @sequence created at @time',
    array(
      '@sequence' => $item->sequence,
      '@time' => date_iso8601($item->created),
    )
  );
}
```

Check your custom callback which returns results as mentioned by David in comment..

Comment: It doesn't work :( I've simply changed hook names with my module name. It's a problem if I call my custom logic simply after $queue->createItem($item), not passing from worker callback?

Comment: Mh, I'm using elysia_cron, the problem seems it, without elysia the function works.